# how to get sum of the row by using column*value in pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Im trying to get  following output. Stuck to get Total.

[image]

Here is my code;

```
def generate_invoice_summary_info():                                                                                                         
    file_path = 'output.xlsx'                                                                                                                
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Invoice Details', usecols="E:F,I,L:M")                                                         

    df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)                                                                                                  
    # df['Total'] = df.groupby(["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"]).agg({'Price': 'sum'}).reset_index()                              

    df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"],columns=['Price','Reporting Frequency','Data Feed'],           
                           aggfunc=len ,fill_value=0,margins=True)                                                                           
    print(df.head())                                                                                                                         
    df.to_excel('a.xlsx',sheet_name='Invoice Summary')
```

Above code produces following output (90% right)
[image]

I got stuck to find the Total column. 
Total column is calcultaed for each row, based on `count* price`

```
Total = count*price column
```

How can I do that in pivot table?
I used margins attribute , but it gives row sum only.

**Edit**
print(df):

```
Price                                           10.4        ...    85.0   All
Reporting Frequency                                M        ...       M      
Data Feed                                        BWH EMAIL  ... StarBOS      
Invoice Cost Centre Invoice Category                        ...              
D3TM                Reseller Non Equity           21    10  ...       0   125
EQUITYEMP           Baileys                        0     7  ...       0    10
                    Energy NSW                     16     0  ...       0    32
                    Far North Queensland           3     0  ...       0     6
                    South East                     6     0  ...       0    16
                    Cooper & Dysart                0     0  ...       0     3
                    Petro Fuel & Lubricants        8     0  ...       0    20
                    South East QLD Fuels           0     0  ...       0    19
R1M                 Retail QLD                    60     0  ...       0   867
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the DataFrame in Python (print?), rather than as an Excel sheet? Also, data/code should be in the post itself, as text, not as images.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have added print(df) output. Also my code is in text. Not image